# BeautifulStoneSoup AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'subtag'

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse some XML that looks like

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d attr="x">
        <e>
        </e>
        <name>
        </name>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c>
      ...
    <c>
  </b>
</a>
```

but I can't figure out how to access `e` or `name` in a loop. This works:

```
print soup.a.b.c.d.e
```

but this doesn't:

```
for subtag in soup.a.b.c:
    print subtag.d.e
```

instead it gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'd'
```

and somewhat unrelatedly, this:

```
print soup.a.b.c.d.name
```

only outputs `d`.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect for the second issue I will have to use `find()` instead because that object already has a `name` attribute. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: What's the goal of this parsing?  Are you tying to extract the first `e` element of each `d` element contained within the first `a.b.c` element?

Comment: I want all the (`d`, `e`, `name`) groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an `AttributeError` because [BSS returns `NavigableString`s](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.0/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py#L601) when you loop over `Tag` instances. Maybe you want to try:

```
soup.a.b.c.findChildren()
#[<d attr="x">
#<e>
#</e>
#<name>
#</name>
#</d>, <e>
#</e>, <name>
#</name>]
```

Regarding the issue w/ `name`: it is [specified as an attribute](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.0/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py#L531), but you can instead do:

```
soup.a.b.c.d.findChildren('name')
#[<name>
#</name>]
```

Set-up code for reference:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as bss
soup = bss(markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

*this:*

```
print soup.a.b.c.d.name
```

*only outputs d.*

This is because `name` conflicts with the built-in `name` attribute of Tag objects.  According to the documentation on [using tags names as members](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Using%20tag%20names%20as%20members), you can use `soup.a.b.c.d.nameTag` instead.

The AttributeError is nicely explained in other answers.  If you want to extract every `(d, e, name)` triple in the entire document, regardless of where the `d` tag appears, you could do something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(doc)
for d in soup.findAll('d'):
    print (d, d.e, d.nameTag)
```